# I get an error whenever I try to read a file in Python, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, file, file-not-found

My code:

```
String = open(r"C:\Users\chloe\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Python code\Python text files\Story\VerbJust.txt", "r").read()
print(String)
```

I have the file stored in the exact folder, but I got an error:``

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "C:\Users\chloe\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Python code\StoryClasses.py", line 47, in <module>     
    VerbTo = ReadFile("VerbTo")   
  File "C:\Users\chloe\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Python code\StoryClasses.py", line 41, in ReadFile     
   string = open(w[variable][0], "r").read() 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'
```

Why is this? Can Python not access OneDrive?

Comment: The error message means you're trying to open a file just named `C`, not `C:\pathname`

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry! But I'm not sure why it would say that, because I didn't put C.

Comment: You must have done that. The code you posted woin't even run, so it's obviously not what you actually have in the script. Post the real code.

Comment: Python doesn't care that it's on OneDrive. The OS handles that.

Comment: Is that really the entire error message? Please copy and paste the full traceback.

Comment: My real code is 140 lines long...

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chloe\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Python code\StoryClasses.py", 
  line 47, in <module>
    VerbTo = ReadFile("VerbTo")
  File "C:\Users\chloe\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Python code\StoryClasses.py", 
  line 41, in ReadFile
    string = open(w[variable][0], "r").read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'`

Comment: If `w[variable]` contains the filename, `w[variable][0]` contains the first character of the filename.

Comment: Oh, thanks. That was a stupid mistake... Sorry.

Comment: Now you understand why I asked you to paste the actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
string = open(w[variable][0], "r").read()
```

it appears that `w[variable]` contains the filename. Adding `[0]` to that uses just the first character of the filename. Get rid of that.

```
string = open(w[variable], "r").read()
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the quotation marks are formatted incorrectly.

Also, I suspect the variable name you chose, "String", may cause some issues.

Try:

```
string = open(r"filepath", "r").read()
print(string)
```

Comment: Why would that variable name cause a problem? The built-in function/class is named `str`.

Comment: What do you mean the parentheses are formatted incorrectly? What's the difference in your code?

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. It keeps talking about a file/directory named C?

Comment: That must be a copying error, otherwise the code will fail with a syntax error.